# Unable to run JavaFX on VSCode using a MacBook (Apple M2)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, arm64

This is the error that `VSCode` keeps displaying:

```bash
(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
```

I installed `Java` through `Homebrew`, and that's the version I'm running in `VSCode`.

I've tried downloading the `Java SDK` version for `ARM64`, but nothing showed up.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71622655/10687680)?

Comment: dup? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72920577/11107541

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the terminal inside Visual Studio code to use the non-Rosetta one i.e. have it use the arm64 one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68781379/how-do-i-change-the-terminal-inside-visual-studio-code-to-use-the-non-rosetta-on)

Comment: Does the simple example also go wrong?  https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: Hello I have't figured it out yet. @willbill solution that leads me to download Azul Zulu is the most reasonable but not sure how to configure it in vs code

Comment: @zcant_code Welcome to StackOverflow. If you find the solution, Please consider answering it and  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)